# Is there a way to make a small-dollar political donation in an american election without ending up on marketing lists?

Tags: united-states, election, campaign-finance

It seems like making any kind of contribution to a political campaign in the US is begging to be deluged in political junk mail (both snail mail and email) for years to come, with your contact information being sold and traded between campaigns long after the current election is done. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure just registering to vote does that.

Comment: Is there a way to *do anything* in an america without ending up on marketing lists?

Answer (score 4):

You can, but there is currently a 50$ limit on anonymous cash donations. There is a $100 limit that requires a check, but a money order would not have address info and unless they search for your name on the internet or phone book or something, you could possibly stay off of mailing lists.

See [Citizen's Guide](http://www.fec.gov/pages/brochures/citizens.shtml)